# Finding the difference between two paths

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm writing a script that will allow me to move a folder and fix an XML based project file.

I'm getting from the user the source and destination paths and saving them in a `pathlib.Path` object.

My question is, how can I use the 2 paths given by the user to find a relative path to the XML project file in order to replace all appearances of this path?

I have tried to use the `relative_to` function, but because the project file is not a parent directory, I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "KeilMoveFile.py", line 50, in <module>
    fix_keil_project(keilPrjFile, objToCopy)
  File "KeilMoveFile.py", line 29, in fix_keil_project
    print(line.replace(str(SrcDstPath.src.relative_to(prjFilePath)),
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 884, in relative_to
    raise ValueError("{!r} does not start with {!r}"
ValueError: 'SI\\SI_Boot\\SiBoot' does not start with 'SI\\SI_Boot\\MDK-ARM\\SI_Boot.uvprojx'
```

My Current Project Layout

```
.
├── _libs
│   ├── src
│   └── inc
└── MDK_arm
    └── projectFile
```

The desiered Project Layout

```
.
├── _libs
|   └── Application
│        ├── src
│        └── inc
├── MDK_arm
    └── projectFile
```

The code I'm currently running to fix the project file

```
def fix_keil_project(prjFilePath, SrcDstPath):
    with fileinput.FileInput(prjFilePath, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        dstStrToReplace = str(SrcDstPath.dst.relative_to(prjFilePath))
        srcStrToReplace = str(SrcDstPath.src.relative_to(prjFilePath))
        for line in file:
            print(line.replace(srcStrToReplace, dstStrToReplace), end='')
```

Comment: You should document your initial folder layout, including the location of the nebulous XML-based project file, your desired result, and the code you've tried.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hopefully it will be more clear now.
Thanks for the help

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe create minimal working code which gives the same error.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you get with `relative_to()`

Comment: code would be more readable if you would first get `src = str(SrcDstPath.src.relative_to(prjFilePath))` and `dst = str(SrcDstPath.dst.relative_to(prjFilePath))` (before `for`-loop) and later use `line.replace(src, dst)`

Comment: @furas I took your tip and cleaned up the code a bit to make it more readable.
I'm not using print since I got an error.

Comment: use `print()` before line which makes error - to see what you have in variables.

Comment: Error shows two pathes `'SI\\SI_Boot\\SiBoot'`, `'SI\\SI_Boot\\MDK-ARM\\SI_Boot.uvprojx'` and I think problem is that `relative_to` doesn't work as you expect. It can find relative only if it is subpath but not if it would need to use `..`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that `relative_to()` search only subfolders but not folder which would need `..`.
You will have to use `os.path.relpath()` instead of module `pathlib`.

---

Error shows two paths `'SI\\SI_Boot\\SiBoot'`, `'SI\\SI_Boot\\MDK-ARM\\SI_Boot.uvprojx'` so I use them in examples. Because I use `Linux` so I tested with `/` instead of `\\`.

---

`pathlib` gives error

```
import pathlib

path1 = 'SI/SI_Boot/SiBoot'
path2 = 'SI/SI_Boot/MDK-ARM/SI_Boot.uvprojx'

src = pathlib.Path(path1)
dst = pathlib.Path(path2)

print(src.relative_to(dst))
#print(dst.relative_to(src))
```

Result: (error like in your question)

```
ValueError: 'SI/SI_Boot/SiBoot' does not start with 'SI/SI_Boot/MDK-ARM/SI_Boot.uvprojx'
```

But `os.path.relpath` gives expected result

```
import os

path1 = 'SI/SI_Boot/SiBoot'
path2 = 'SI/SI_Boot/MDK-ARM/SI_Boot.uvprojx'

print(os.path.relpath(path1, path2))
print(os.path.relpath(path2, path1))
```

Result:

```
../../SiBoot
../MDK-ARM/SI_Boot.uvprojx
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I looked for